# Passing a dictionary to a new function in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, parameter-passing, pickle

If I create a dictionary that I need to access in multiple functions what would be the best way to pass it?

What I currently am doing keeps reseting the dictionary to empty. If I print in the addDictionary() I get the result I want. However, when I go to look up a element using the key in lookUpEntry(), I can't find it. When I print I get an empty dictionary. I also have to eventually pickle and unpickle so if anyone has any feedback on that, that would also help.

```
import pickle

def dictionary():
addressBook = {}

return addressBook

def addPerson():
personLastName = input("Enter the last name of "
                   "the person you want to add: ").lower()
personFirstName = input("Please enter the first name of "
                        "the person you want to add: ")

localPart = input("Please enter the local part of the email address")
while not localPart.isalnum():
    localPart = input("Please enter a valid input, a-z and numbers 0-9: ")

domain = input("Please enter the domain of the email addres: ")
while not domain.isalnum():
    domain = input("Please enter a valid input, a-z and numbers 0-9: ")

topLevelDomain = input("Please enter the top level domain, examples: com, net, org: ")
while not topLevelDomain.isalnum() or len(topLevelDomain) > 3:
     topLevelDomain = input("Please enter only letters, a-z and not more then 3 characters: ")

personEmail = localPart + "@" + domain + "." + topLevelDomain

personStreetAddress = input("Please enter house number and street of the person you want to add: ")
personCityState = input("Please enter the city, state abbreviation and zipcode of the person you want to add: ")

personPhone = input("Please enter the phone number of the person you want to add: ")

personPhoneStr = personPhone.strip("-")

while not personPhoneStr.isdigit() and not len(personPhoneStr) == 10:
    personPhone = input("Error. That is not a valid phone number. Try again: ")

    personPhoneStr = personPhone.strip("-")

return personLastName, personFirstName, personEmail, personStreetAddress, personCityState, personPhone


def addDictionary():
addressBook = dictionary()

personLastName, personFirstName, personEmail, personStreetAddress, personCityState, personPhone = addPerson()

addressBook[personLastName] = personFirstName, personEmail, personStreetAddress, personCityState, personPhone

print(personFirstName,personLastName, "has been added to the address book!")

print(addressBook)

return addressBook


def lookUpEntry():
addressBook = dictionary()

keyName = input("Enter the last name of the person you are trying to find.")

while not keyName in addressBook:
    keyName = input("That name is not in the address book. Please try again.").lower()

x = input("Enter '1' if you want to look up a email. Enter '2' if you want to look "
          "up a persons address. Enter '3' to look up a persons phone number: ")
if x == "1":
    print("The email of", addressBook[keyName[0]], keyName, "is:", addressBook[keyName[1]])
elif x == "2":
    print("The address of", addressBook[keyName[0]], keyName, "is:", addressBook[keyName[2]], addressBook[keyName[3]])
elif x == "3":
    print("The phone number of", addressBook[keyName[0]], keyName, "is:", addressBook[keyName[4]])
else:
    print("Sorry that item is not stored in this address book.")

def main():
addDictionary()
lookUpEntry()
```

main()

Comment: Please indent your code correctly

Answer (score 0):

Currently you define `dictionary` as

```
def dictionary():
    addressBook = {}
    return addressBook
```

Here you create a new dictionary every time it is called.  Try replacing this with

```
# a global dictionary
_addressBook = {}
def dictionary():
    return _addressBook
```

Comment: as your current code stands, where you don't pass a `dict` to either `addDictionary` or `lookupEntry`, it will pretty much require a global

Comment: Okay what would be the best method to pass the dict ? Sorry I had mono and missed the class on passing values to functions. Not my strong suit.